# Is Entity Framework 6.0 DBContex automatically closing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, iis-7, dbcontext

Is DBcontext connection closing automatically? I have used EF6 and there is no connection open or close that because of context is bind with connection string in config file. EF stored procedures are connected and able to do transaction.

Asp.net project

{ 
...
    return DBContext.ValidUserName(userName).SingleOrDefault();
}

Want to clarify whether connection is close automatically or have to do it manually? Is this cause to exceeding the pool in IIS.

Comment: If the context isnt disposed, most likely not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're using it, and you haven't provided much information in your question. But the short answer is that Entity framework manages connections for you, and you generally don't have to worry about opening or closing connections manually.

From Microsoft documentation:

> Object Services exposes the *EntityConnection* by means of the *Connection* property. This enables you to manage the connection and transactions or to supply your own *EntityConnection*. This is useful when you want to hold open a connection within a short-lived object context to improve performance or to explicitly control transactions. The same provider connection used by the Entity Framework can be shared with other parts of an application.
>
> The following considerations apply when managing connections:
>
> - The object context will open the connection if it is not already open before an operation. If the object context opens the connection during an operation, it will always close the connection when the operation is complete.
> - If you manually open the connection, the object context will not close it. Calling Close or Dispose will close the connection.
> - If the object context creates the connection, the connection will always be disposed when the context is disposed.
> - In a long-running object context, you must ensure that the context is disposed when it is no longer required.
> - If you supply an open *EntityConnection* for the object context, you must ensure that it is disposed.

Comment: In this case there is no manually binding, Connection is given at the time EF is initialization. The Issue is  IIS pool is exceeding. This is EF6 context.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#connections):

> By default, the context manages connections to the database. The context opens and closes connections as needed.
>   For example, the context opens a connection to execute a query, and then closes the connection when all the result sets have been processed.

When you are using DbContext within a web application, you should consider the section Lifetime too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime

> Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the
>   context:
>
> - When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a context instance per form. This lets you use
>     change-tracking functionality that context provides.
> - If the context instance is created by a dependency injection container, it is usually the responsibility of the container to
>     dispose the context.
> - If the context is created in application code, remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
> - When working with long-running context consider the following:
>
>   - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause
>       performance issues.
>   - The context is not thread-safe, therefore it should not be shared across multiple threads doing work on it concurrently.
>   - If an exception causes the context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
>   - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated
>       grows.